# sip authorization header cannot be added

Tags: java, asterisk, jain-sip

I have a question about authentication with jain sip library. I am using jain sip for registering sip accounts to Asterisk server.
As soon as I try to add `AuthorizationHeader` the following error message appears:

`The method makeAuthHeader(HeaderFactory, Response, Request, String, String) is undefined for the type Utils`

Here is the code snippet:

```
AuthorizationHeader authHeader = Utils.makeAuthHeader(
                headerFactory, response, request, userId, password);
        request.addHeader(authHeader);
```

It seems that cannot method `makeAuthHeader()` cannot be found.

Code SipClientServiceImpl.java:

```
@Service("clientService")
public class SipClientServiceImpl implements SipClientService, SipListener {

    SipFactory sipFactory; // Used to access the SIP API.
    SipStack sipStack; // The SIP stack.
    SipProvider sipProvider; // Used to send SIP messages.
    MessageFactory messageFactory; // Used to create SIP message factory.
    HeaderFactory headerFactory; // Used to create SIP headers.
    AddressFactory addressFactory; // Used to create SIP URIs.
    ListeningPoint listeningPoint; // SIP listening IP address/port.
    Properties properties; // Other properties.

    // Objects keeping local configuration.
    String ip; // The local IP address.
    int port = 6060; // The local port.
    String protocol = "udp"; // The local protocol (UDP).
    int tag = (new Random()).nextInt(); // The local tag.
    Address contactAddress; // The contact address.
    ContactHeader contactHeader;
    String asteriskServer = "10.0.0.0.0";
    int asteriksPort = 5060;
    String sipPasswordForAllAccounts = "1234";
    Request request = null;
    Response response = null;

    private ClientTransaction inviteTid;
    long invco = 1;

    public void registerToAsterisk(String userId) throws ParseException,
            InvalidArgumentException, PeerUnavailableException,
            TransportNotSupportedException, ObjectInUseException,
            TooManyListenersException {
        init();
        try {
            // Get the destination address from the text field.
            Address addressTo = addressFactory.createAddress("sip:" + userId
                    + '@' + asteriskServer + ":" + asteriksPort);

            // Create the request URI for the SIP message.
            javax.sip.address.URI requestURI = addressTo.getURI();

            // Create the SIP message headers.

            // The "Via" headers.
            ArrayList viaHeaders = new ArrayList();
            ViaHeader viaHeader = this.headerFactory.createViaHeader(this.ip,
                    this.port, "udp", null);
            viaHeaders.add(viaHeader);
            // The "Max-Forwards" header.
            MaxForwardsHeader maxForwardsHeader = this.headerFactory
                    .createMaxForwardsHeader(70);
            // The "Call-Id" header.
            CallIdHeader callIdHeader = this.sipProvider.getNewCallId();
            // The "CSeq" header.
            CSeqHeader cSeqHeader = this.headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(1L,
                    "REGISTER");
            // The "From" header.
            FromHeader fromHeader = this.headerFactory.createFromHeader(
                    this.contactAddress, String.valueOf(this.tag));
            // The "To" header.
            ToHeader toHeader = this.headerFactory.createToHeader(addressTo,
                    null);

            // AuthorizationHeader authHeader = Utils.makeAuthHeader(
            // headerFactory, response, request, userId,
            // sipPasswordForAllAccounts);

            // Create the REGISTER request.
            Request request = this.messageFactory.createRequest(requestURI,
                    "REGISTER", callIdHeader, cSeqHeader, fromHeader, toHeader,
                    viaHeaders, maxForwardsHeader);
            // Add the "Contact" header to the request.
            request.addHeader(contactHeader);
            // request.addHeader(authHeader);

            // Send the request statelessly through the SIP provider.
            this.sipProvider.sendRequest(request);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void processRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {

    }

    public void processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent) {
        Response response = responseEvent.getResponse();
        System.out.println(response);
        ClientTransaction tid = responseEvent.getClientTransaction();
        CSeqHeader cseq = (CSeqHeader) response.getHeader(CSeqHeader.NAME);

        System.out.println("Response received : Status Code = "
                + response.getStatusCode() + " " + cseq);
        // if (tid == null) {
        // System.out.println("Stray response -- dropping ");
        // return;
        // }
        try {
            if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED
                    || response.getStatusCode() == Response.UNAUTHORIZED) {
                AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper = ((SipStackExt) sipStack)
                        .getAuthenticationHelper(new AccountManagerImpl(),
                                headerFactory);
                inviteTid = authenticationHelper.handleChallenge(response, tid,
                        sipProvider, 5, false);
                inviteTid.sendRequest();
                invco++;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    public void processTimeout(TimeoutEvent timeoutEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void processIOException(IOExceptionEvent exceptionEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void processTransactionTerminated(
            TransactionTerminatedEvent transactionTerminatedEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void processDialogTerminated(
            DialogTerminatedEvent dialogTerminatedEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void init() {
        // Get the local IP address.
        try {
            this.ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            // Create the SIP factory and set the path name.
            this.sipFactory = SipFactory.getInstance();
            this.sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist");
            // Create and set the SIP stack properties.
            this.properties = new Properties();
            this.properties.setProperty("javax.sip.STACK_NAME", "stack");
            // Create the SIP stack.
            this.sipStack = this.sipFactory.createSipStack(this.properties);
            // Create the SIP message factory.
            this.messageFactory = this.sipFactory.createMessageFactory();
            // Create the SIP header factory.
            this.headerFactory = this.sipFactory.createHeaderFactory();
            // Create the SIP address factory.
            this.addressFactory = this.sipFactory.createAddressFactory();
            // Create the SIP listening point and bind it to the local IP
            // address, port and protocol.
            this.listeningPoint = this.sipStack.createListeningPoint(this.ip,
                    this.port, this.protocol);
            // Create the SIP provider.
            this.sipProvider = this.sipStack
                    .createSipProvider(this.listeningPoint);
            // Add our application as a SIP listener.
            this.sipProvider.addSipListener(this);
            // Create the contact address used for all SIP messages.
            this.contactAddress = this.addressFactory.createAddress("sip:"
                    + this.ip + ":" + this.port);
            // Create the contact header used for all SIP messages.
            this.contactHeader = this.headerFactory
                    .createContactHeader(contactAddress);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
javax.sip.SipException: Unexpected exception 
at gov.nist.javax.sip.clientauthutils.AuthenticationHelperImpl.handleChallenge(AuthenticationHelperImpl.java:298)
at com.musala.ving.voip.SipClientServiceImpl.processResponse(SipClientServiceImpl.java:152)
at gov.nist.javax.sip.EventScanner.deliverEvent(EventScanner.java:296)
at gov.nist.javax.sip.EventScanner.run(EventScanner.java:519)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.clientauthutils.AuthenticationHelperImpl.handleChallenge(AuthenticationHelperImpl.java:149)
    ... 4 more

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on as Utils is not really an API. This example should help you https://svn.java.net/svn/jsip~svn/trunk/src/examples/authorization/ShootistAuth.java . Otherwise post full code and logs,

Comment: Thank you for your response! 
Post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Utils is not part of the API and it simply doesn't have the method you are trying to use. The best way to do client auth is to use the example from https://svn.java.net/svn/jsip~svn/trunk/src/examples/authorization/ShootistAuth.java

This is the relevant part:

```
if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED
                    || response.getStatusCode() == Response.UNAUTHORIZED) {
                AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper = 
                    ((SipStackExt) sipStack).getAuthenticationHelper(new AccountManagerImpl(), headerFactory);

                inviteTid = authenticationHelper.handleChallenge(response, tid, sipProvider, 5);

                inviteTid.sendRequest();

                invco++;
            }
```

Comment: Do I need to add the following code to the `public void processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent` method? For some reason it does not allow me to get registration even after following the steps in the snippet. :/

Comment: Most likely yes. But it depends. If you are doing registration make sure to adapt the code so that it does REGISTER transaction as opposed to INVITE.

Comment: It seems that the following row is the problem

`inviteTid = authenticationHelper.handleChallenge(response, tid,
      sipProvider, 5, false);` It trows SipException

Comment: The tid is null. You should send requests in the context of a client transaction to get a non-null tid, but even then there are more robust ways to do it. Use something like this to have something working ClientTransaction ct = sipProvider .getNewClientTransaction(yourRegisterRequest);ct.sendRequest();

Comment: All right I managed to fix it without trowing the exception using `this.sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request).sendRequest();` 
And the response after that is 403 Forbidden. The credentials should be set somehow.

Comment: Inside AccountManagerImpl

Comment: What I have in `AccountManagerImpl` is `public class AccountManagerImpl implements AccountManager {

 public UserCredentials getCredentials(
   ClientTransaction challengedTransaction, String realm) {
  return new UserCredentialsImpl("6034", "10.0.0.0", "1234");
 }

}`

Comment: and it does not set it

Comment: Make sure asterisk recognizes itself as the 10.0.0.0 realm, that's a weird realm. Typically the realm is a FQDN. Best way to debug is to see asterisk logs or compare the SIP messages with a working phone stream.

Comment: It is not the real realm. 10.0.0.*** . Actually it is the vm where the asterisk is installed.

Comment: I tested with wrong credentials :X. Vladimir, thank you very much for your responses. I managed to register sip user with this. : )

Answer (score 0):

The class Utils doesn't own this method as you can see here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.sip/jain-sip-ri/1.2.203/gov/nist/javax/sip/Utils.java
You have to use something different but I cannot find anything about what class/method to use.

Comment: Well, I noticed that. This is the reason posting a question here :) Thanks